# How is a bottom line added with this layer-list drawable?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-drawable, layer-list

I want to have a bottom line in a view. The following drawable somehow adds a bottom border:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape
                android:shape="rectangle">
            <!-- Set the border color of your layout here -->
            <solid android:color="@color/red" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- This is for border bottom but
    you can change this according to your need -->
    <item android:bottom="2dp" >
        <shape
                android:shape="rectangle">
            <!-- Set the background color of your layout here -->
            <solid android:color="@color/green" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

The result of this is:

[image]

**Problem**:
1) I don't understand how this works at all. It seems this is some trick using margins to get a red bottom border but I don't really get it.
2) I need to be able to add a bottom border but I don't want to set any specific background color for the whole view. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is telling the system from where to start this item layout.
Since here we have bottom 2dp so this layout start  2dp from bottom.
Change  bottom to end,start or other options for more understanding.

Comment: What do you mean by `where to start this item`?

Comment: But the `bottom` is in the definition for color `green` which takes the whole view

Comment: that layout starts  bottom to top  leaving 2dp in bottom and is drawing over the layout which is red color so red color is visible in only bottom 2dp

Comment: Is it that the drawing starts bottom to top? Or is it that the second rectangle drawn over the first has `2dp` padding in the bottom so that we can see only the 2 dp of the first one? I could not find where is this behavior documented

Comment: try changing tag to end,start. i found this solution. Dont know about the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For *2) I need to be able to add a bottom border but I don't want to set any specific background color for the whole view. Is that possible?*

replace your drawable with below code:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:left="-2dp"
    android:right="-2dp"
    android:top="-2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        <!--Uncomment this if you wnat to set any background color to 
    your rectangle
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />-->

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/red" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: If I remove the `<solid android:color...` then the whole view becomes red

Comment: Can you set it `<solid android:color="#ffffff" />` if you want no color to the view

Comment: That is white though. If I set `@android:color/transparent` the everything becomes red

Comment: @Jim, I have updated my code, please use the above drawable

Comment: Can you explain how this works? What are the negative dps for?

Comment: We have a rectangle, which has a stoke of 1dp from all sides, now we want to keep border at the bottom only, so I am cutting it down from rest other 3 sides.

Comment: I would suggest you, try by adding or removing negative values from <item..> in the android studio so that you will be more clear about it's working. Adding ` android:bottom="-2dp"` in your <item..> you will get to know how it works.